# Tricky Integration substitution problem

Tags: integration, substitution

The problem is:

$$
1+ \int_a^x f(t)t^{-6}dt\,=5x^{-1}, x>0
$$

f(x) = ?
a = ?

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Use the fundamental theorem of calculus. Differentiate both sides wrt $x$:

$f(x)x^{-6} = -5x^{-2}$

$f(x) = -5x^4$

Now put that back into the original equation, which becomes:

$$1 + \int_a^x -\frac{5}{t^2}dt = \frac 5x$$

Solving, we get $\displaystyle 1 -\frac 5a = 0$

$a = 5$